# T-SQL DateDiff return absurd results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried datediff in my db and it returns absurd result. How it is possible? Where I do mistake? Can Anybody Help me?

[Here is screen of my table in database](http://postimg.org/image/dm4k29vpz/)

```
DECLARE @sql_statement nvarchar(250)
Declare @dal  date
declare @dat varchar(20)
set @dal = '07.08.2015'
SET @dat = Convert(Varchar(20),@dal,101)
SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT datediff(yy,'+@dat+',DateEx) FROM ExData '
EXECute sp_executesql  @sql_statement
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the *"absurd"* results you're seeing? (and possibly also *pointing out* what the *"absurd"* results really should be.....)

Comment: it's returns 115 year diffrence but real diff is only one day

Comment: First of all - you need to put your **date string** (`@dat`) into **single quotes** inside your `@sql_statement`. : `SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT datediff(year, ''' + @dat + ''', DateEx) FROM ExData '`

Comment: Why not just pass '@'dal.   Debug 101  select '@'dal, DateEx, datediff(yy, '@'dal,DateEx)   ignore the ' as had to use them so it would not think user

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that dynamic query:

```
SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT datediff(yy,'+@dat+',DateEx) FROM ExData '
```

should be (please note double *single quotation marks* added -> `''`'+@dat+'`''`)

```
SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT datediff(yy,'''+@dat+''',DateEx) FROM ExData '
```

Without those quotation marks, query can be evaluated as

```
SELECT datediff(yy,07/08/2015,GETDATE())
```

and because

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 07/08/2015) -- SELECT 07/08/2015 -> 0
```

gives

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

the end result is `115`.

Solution #1: I would use a static query (no `EXEC sp_executesql`)

```
SELECT datediff(yy,@dal,DateEx), ... FROM ExData
```

Solution #2: or I would use `sp_executesql` with parameters (but not in this case):

```
SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT datediff(yy,@pDate,DateEx), ... FROM ExData '
EXECute sp_executesql  @sql_statement, '@pDate DATE', @pDate = @dal
```

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing - that dynamic SQL is totally unnecessary and makes things to wonky....

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong formatting parameter here:

```
SET @dat = Convert(Varchar(20),@dal,101)
```

For dates separated with dots (the 'german' format) use code 104

```
SET @dat = Convert(Varchar(20),@dal,104)
```

A list of all formats can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
This is a very handy list; I use it near-daily.

Also, I believe the date within your dynamic query should be between two quotes:

```
SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT datediff(yy,'''+@dat+''',DateEx) FROM ExData '
```

Why do you execute this query in such a dynamic fashion? Why not just

```
SELECT datediff(yy, @dat, DateEx) FROM ExData
```

and scrap the sp_execute?